# How to build SSIS package without SQL Server Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, data-migration

I'm doing data migration between two SQL Server 2008 database using SSIS because I need to do some data transformation. I guess I need to use Business Intelligence Developement Studio which I have on my develop machine. But because I don't have SQL Server Standard Edition on my develop machine. The BIDS do not allow me to build the SSIS package. Is there any work around? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you installed BIDS, did you also install the client tools for SQL Server?

Alternatively, you could remote to the dev server and devlop the package directly on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You would normally install [SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/Developer.aspx) on your development box.

> SQL Server 2008 Developer enables
>   developers to build and test
>   applications that run on SQL Server on
>   32-bit, ia64, and x64 platforms. SQL
>   Server 2008 Developer includes all of
>   the functionality of Enterprise
>   Edition, but is licensed only for
>   development, test, and demo use.

Comment: Thanks! But I think it also cost money. Is there any way to build the package with Express Edition? Or the present of the integration service on development environment is enssential for designing the package?

Comment: Does your company have a MSDN subscription? Check, but I think you get a number of developer licences...

Comment: We have few subscriptions. But we decided not to use them unrestrictly. Thanks Wheat, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess what BIDS does is just use those assemblies come along with SSIS to generate the .dtsx file(which is actually xml). Am I right? If it is, I think maybe some 3rd party tool(best to be free) can do that job too.